# How to make two foreign keys to same model unique together?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, unique, foreign-key-relationship

Let's say I have a relationship class such as:

```
class Friendship(models.Model):
    person1 = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='person1')
    person2 = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='person2')
```

so I want to make this object unique for a pair of `Person`s. If I simply do `unique_together = (("person1", "person2"),)` then I can end up with two `Friendship` objects where

```
FS1.person1 = A, FS1.person2 = B
FS2.person1 = B, FS2.person2 = A
```

I do **not** want this. I want a unique friendship object between two people. So how can I ensure that there is -at most- one `Friendship` object for any pair of `Person`s?

Thanks !

Comment: check this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098718/how-do-i-model-a-symmetric-relationship-with-django

Comment: @Gocht thanks! From that post it looks so difficult that I might choose to deal with duplicate Friendship's instead of dealing with those :) I wish there was an easier way..

Comment: I think that's what you need, because for every symetrical relation will be only one record in the trough table.

Comment: It looks like it, yes. But I've always been afraid of many-to-many relationships with Django. Anyway, seems like there is no easier solution?

Comment: For cases like this, exists symetrical relationships, that's the way I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use model.clean method:

```
class Friendship(models.Model):
    person1 = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='person1')
    person2 = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='person2')

    def clean(self):
        direct = FriendShip.objects.filter(person1 = self.person1, person2 = self.person2)
        reverse = FriendShip.objects.filter(person1 = self.person2, person2 = self.person1) 

        if direct.exists() or reverse.exists():
            raise ValidationError({'key':'Message')})
```