# How would I implement a "unique_together" constraint going both ways?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm seeking `unique_together` functionality with two fields that goes both ways. Say, if I had two fields like this:

```
class Pair(models.Model):

    requester = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='pairing_requester')
    accepter = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='pairing_accepter')
    class Meta():
        unique_together = ('requester', 'accepter')
```

How can I make sure that not only is one combination of two Profiles (requester=a, accepter=b) unique, but the other way around as well? (requester=b, accepter=a). I don't mean to create two Pair objects. I mean one pair would make sure that the two Profiles cannot be created in another pair with the roles exchanged.

edit: if using `unique_together` isn't the right method, how might I go about achieving similar results? Making sure that any number of two Profiles will only lead to a single Pair object.

Comment: both ways should work I think.

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal it does not. I am able to create another Pair object with the `requester` pointing to the (previously) accepter, and the accepter pointing to the (previously) requester. Which makes sense, as it's just a completely new object with new properties.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33449157/2282638

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal does not work. That clean method assumes both ways are created separately, then checks if either exists. Not exactly what I'm after

Comment: I think using **unique_together** will give you the result you want.

Comment: @VijeshVenugopal it does not..