# Many-to-many fields with intermediate tables must not be symmetrical

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to figure out how to store prices between cities in my project so I can work with that comfortabely and admin can change those prices comfortably.

I've decided to create a `through` model, according to this [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4098843/3371056), which is called `Ride`.

But when I do `makemigrations`, Django returns:

> va_app.City.rides: (fields.E332) Many-to-many fields with intermediate tables must not be symmetrical.

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country')
    _close_cities = models.ManyToManyField('City', blank=True, related_name='close_cities_set',symmetrical=True)
    rides = models.ManyToManyField('self',through='Ride')

class Ride(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

Do you know how to make it work?

PS> The only thing I want is to be able to simple access the price (like `City.price(City)` or something else and admin to be able to change prices.

Comment: The trick is, still setting as symmetrical=False, but it can used as symmetrical, check this:  https://charlesleifer.com/blog/self-referencing-many-many-through/   https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/08/14/creating-recursive-symmetrical-many-to-many-relationships-in-django/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty clear you can't have M2M relation with `intermediate` table and `symmetrical=True`, it must be `symmetrical=False`.

So try with:

```
rides = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Ride', symmetrical=False)
```

However, I think something is wrong with your model structure, you have two M2M fields pointing to `self`? I'm not sure whats the purpose of the `Rides` model, but maybe this model should only have `FKs` to `city`.